# How can i convert an UTC datetime?

Tags: .net, datetime, timezone, timezone-offset

I have the following date provided via an XML file

```
2013-12-13T19:00:00+01:00
```

I would like to store it as DateTime within my database with ZERO UTC offset.

Unfortunatelly my webserver has the following TimeZone info which destroys my conversion logic...

```
-06:00:00
(UTC-06:00) Central Time (US & Canada)
Central Standard Time
```

How can i accomplish this one? I am totally lost!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With [the `ToUniversalTime` method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetimeoffset.touniversaltime%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)?

```
DateTimeOffset.Parse("2013-12-13T19:00:00+01:00").ToUniversalTime()
-> 2013-12-13 06:00:00 PM +00:00
```

Comment: I think the OP's problem was that they used `DateTime.Parse` instead of `DateTimeOffset.Parse`.

Comment: @Chocol8: `DateTimeOffset` was [added in .NET 3.5](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/bclteam/archive/2007/06/14/datetimeoffset-a-new-datetime-structure-in-net-3-5-justin-van-patten.aspx) to handle this type of scenario.

Comment: Ok. Now i 'll start taking drugs. While running that on server side and adding the ".LocalDateTime" the result is 12/13/2013 12:00:00 PM

Comment: @Chocol8: Which is to be expected, since your local timezone is `UTC-06:00'. :)

Comment: Good answer.  Also, proper use of `DateTimeOffset` and `TimeZoneInfo`, and understanding `DateTime.Kind` will let you write code that doesn't care what the time zone of your server is set to.  That should always be the goal.